# unable to move or delete file in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am not a programmer by trade, but I do write some batch files and a few powershell scripts for work.

Here is my current script that I am stuck with.

```
Copy-Item C:\thirdpartydaily\THIRDPARTY.XLS -Destination C:\thirdpartydaily\oldreports\thirdparty.xls
Get-ChildItem C:\thirdpartydaily\oldreports\THIRDPARTY.XLS -Recurse |  % {

# $_.name is the name with extension but since you want to
# specify .MOD I used the basename
$name = $_.basename

$creationtime = get-date $_.creationtime -format "dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm"
$newname = $creationtime + '_' + $name + '.xls'

Rename-Item $_ -newname $newname
Write-Host Before
start-sleep -Seconds 5
Write-Host After
Remove-Item -Path C:\thirdpartydaily\THIRDPARTY.XLS -Force
}
```

The problem comes in at the last line "remove-item -path c:\thirdpartydaily\thirdpartydaily.cls -Force".  One computer "A" it fails because it is in use.  It then references the line of the script that is attempting to move it.  I added the -Force to try and "make it work".

I have the same problem with this line of code

Move-Item -Path C:\thirdpartydaily\THIRDPARTY.XLS -Destination c:\thirdpartydaily\oldreports\thirdparty.xls

It again fails because the file is in use and references this line of code that is attempting to move it.

I take the script to computer "B" and it works flawlessly.  Both are imaged from the same source, but we have no group policies so it is possible someone made a change on one of the computers that allows it to run on "A" but not "B".  My question is, how do I make this script run on
"A"?

Comment: Is it possible that file is in-use due to the "third party" process or, say, antivirus scans?  Is there a reason you're doing this as a copy, rename, and remove?  That's otherwise known as and simplified to just a move.

Comment: It is part of a larger script.  I wish to time stamp the file.  I copy it to the \oldreports\ directory, rename it, and then delete it out of the original directory.  If there is a simpler way to do that, I am all ears.  I started with the move-item command, but it was giving me the same "unable to access" the file.  I am starting to think there are differences between the 2 computers that are allowing it to be deleted on one and not the other.  The core problem appears to be the deleting of the file.

Comment: You could simplify it to `$file = Get-Item -Path 'C:\thirdpartydaily\THIRDPARTY.XLS'; $newname = (get-date $file.creationtime -format "dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm") + '_' + $file.basename + '.xls'; $file | Move-Item -Destination "C:\thirdpartydaily\oldreports\$newname"`, though that wouldn't address the file-in-use issue.  Are you able to move/rename/delete the original file in Explorer or Command Prompt?  I'd use a tool like Process Explorer to identify what process has that file open.  It shouldn't be a permissions issue because that would cause a different error message.

Comment: I appreciate that answer.  I will try that as well. The answer has something to do with running powershell as admin.  I ran Powershell ISE as admin (right click, "run as administrator" and the script works fine.  There are no problems deleting the file.   If I run it without elevation, it does not work.  I am unsure why it runs fine on the 2nd computer, though it may be the admin rights for that user?  So, bottom line, I believe it has something to do with the admin rights for the 2nd computer.